# Getting multiple video renderers in directshow.net in c#

Tags: c#, directshow

I have 4 separate video devices connected to their respective video renderers and I'd like to show the video renderers in 4 separate windows/panels.

With the

```
IVideoWindow GetSecondRenderer()
    {
        IEnumFilters enumFilters;
        ArrayList filtersArray = new ArrayList();

        IFilterGraph filterGraph = (IFilterGraph)m_FilterGraph;
        filterGraph.EnumFilters(out enumFilters);

        IBaseFilter[] filters = new IBaseFilter[1];
        IntPtr fetched = new IntPtr();

        while (enumFilters.Next(1, filters,fetched) == 0)
        {
            IVideoWindow ivw = filters[0] as IVideoWindow;
            if (ivw != null)
            {
                IntPtr outPtr = new IntPtr();
                ivw.get_Owner(out outPtr);
                if (outPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return ivw;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and then using videoWindow2 = GetSecondRenderer(); code I managed to get 2 videos to show,but as I'm still very new to this I can't seem to enumerate the other 2 video renderes. Could someone help with showing how to modify this to be able to get the other 2?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just returns first found video renderer. Instead of returning from the while loop make a list of IVideoWindows and add found renderers to it. Then, when the loop finishes, return whole list.

Comment: Made it so that theres a different method for each camera as this was easier but this will do well when I want to do something fancier. Thanks